# how to fix image for all scree sizes in bootstrap or css?

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, frontend

```
<section class="wt-section hero-large position-relative overflow-hidden mt-md-2">
    <div class="hero-img bg-overlay" data-overlay="0" style="background-image: url(images/officeemp.jpg); height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: scale-down"; data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-easing="linear" data-aos-delay="50"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center my-5">
            <div class="col-md-6 py-5" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-easing="linear" data-aos-delay="100" style="margin-top: 300px">
                <!-- heading -->
                <h1 class="text-uppercase mb-3 display-4 font-weight-bolder">
          Best Business Services
        </h1>
                <p class="lead text-dark">Lets Grow Your Business Togather</p>
                <div class=" mb-0">
                    <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-pill btn-primary mr-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
            Quick Call
          </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the problem exactly? , witch image in witch screen size has problem?

Comment: The image which is showing on the screen is perfect for desktop view but when we want to see it on  the mobile view its dimension changes its zoom in automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a container-fluid class in the parent div of the image.

Exp: Bootstrap 4

```
<div class= "container.fluid">
    <img src="(your image)">
</div>
```

Exp: CSS3

```
<div style="margin:auto;height:auto;width:100%;">
    <img src="(your image)">
</div>
```